# Are the elements of the argv array always contiguous in memory?

Tags: c, unix, posix

On Linux, the elements of the argv array always seem to occupy contiguous positions in memory, i.e. the first character of argv[n+1] immediately follows the terminating nul byte of argv[n], for n = 0...(argc-1).

Is this guaranteed to be the case on all POSIX systems/all C implementations?

Comment: Try putting extra spaces between your command line arguments and check again.

Comment: @user3386109: I seriously doubt that that would make any difference. It's likely that *for a given implementation* the argument strings will be allocated contiguously, but there's no guarantee (and no good reason I can think of to depend on it).

Comment: @KeithThompson One possible implementation is to use `strtok` to break the command line down in place.  The argument strings would then be non-contiguous if the command line started with extra spaces. But regardless, I agree that there's no guarantee, and no good reason to depend on the strings being contiguous.

Comment: @user3386109: `strtok` isn't really an option for any reasonable shell; among other things, it won't handle quoting.

Answer (score 9):

This is not guaranteed. Neither by C, neither by POSIX.

Comment: Isn't it guaranteed by the implementation that an array is a continguous block of memory? If that is so, then why should this be an exception?

Comment: @ManojAwasthi `argv` is an array of `char` pointers, i.e., `char *argv[N]`. The string pointers are guaranteed to be contiguous in memory, not the strings.