# Shouldn't the element after the last element in an array be zero?

Tags: c

I have this C-code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {


int a[12];
printf("%d\n", a[10]);
printf("%d\n", a[11]);
printf("%d, this is element with index 12\n", a[12]);
printf("%d\n", a[13]);

char v[12];
printf("\n");
printf("%d\n", v[10]);
printf("%d\n", v[11]);
printf("%d, this is element with index 12\n", v[12]);
printf("%d\n", v[13]);

/*
Output:

0
0
249560352, this is element with index 12
232

0
0
-96, this is element with index 12
-4


*/
}
```

Isn't index element number 12 supposed to be zero? Because the array is of length 12, and the indexing starts with 0 and goes to 11, and the element after the last element is supposed to be the null terminator?

Comment: Accessing `a[12]` or `a[13]` or `v[12]` or `v[13]` is **undefined behaviour**. *"The element after the last element is supposed to be the null terminator*" – false. Moreover, the arrays have not been initialised, so printing any in-range element is undefined behaviour too.

Comment: Closely related: [Why don't numeric arrays end with a '\0' or null character?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19331941/2402272)

Comment: Even if a sentinel value is used, that element still needs to be within the array definition's size.

Comment: In short: no. Index number 12 is outside the memory allocated for the arrays. It is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) to access them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NUL`-termination is only automatic for string literals (e.g. `char foo[] = "abc";` creates an array of four `char` values, equivalent to typing `char foo[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}`; if you explicitly size the array though, it can chop off the `NUL`, so `char foo[3] = "abc"` would not be `NUL` terminated for lack of room). C arrays in general store no additional zero at the end, it's up to you to track the length and not access outside the available bounds.

When you access outside the defined bounds, you invoke undefined behavior. The value might be zero. The value might be any other value. It might cause your program to crash. It might cause subtle memory corruption that changes all behavior from there on out, and leads to simultaneously uploading all your financial data to hackers, then formatting your hard drive (probably not, but buffer overruns are actually the baseline source of many software vulnerabilities, so it might not happen by accident, but you might be letting a hacker do it on purpose later). Don't do undefined things and expect useful results.

Comment: Another special case is `argv`. It's guaranteed to have `NULL` at `argv[argc]`

Comment: @Barmar: Sure. Heck, IIRC, I believe it's actually laid out (not sure if it's a guarantee, but it holds in practice on the machines I've bothered to test on) such that the data for each argument is actually stored contiguously, with `NUL` separators, e.g. a program invoked as `./a.out foo bar` would have `argv[0]` point to a single array that's equivalent to `"./a.out\0foo\0bar"`, with `argv[1]` just being a pointer further along in the same array (pointing at the `f` character).

Comment: Also accessing uninitialized variables is in principle undefined behavior. It is well discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that string literals are NULL terminated, but if you initialize a char array with insufficient length with a string literal (e.g. `char arr[4] = "hello";`) then accessing that char array out of bounds is UB.

Comment: @Chris: Sure, expanded my parenthetical.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, yes, it is in the C language specification that if `main` is declared with the two-parameter form as `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` then `argv[argc]` is a null pointer.  In C17, this is in paragraph 5.1.2.2.1/2.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The contiguous layout is not specified anywhere, it's just the simplest, most common implementation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765640/are-the-elements-of-the-argv-array-always-contiguous-in-memory

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yeah, I wasn't unsure on that, I was talking about the secondary relationship between the pointers in `argv` (that they all in turn point to different places in within a single contiguous buffer, separated by `NUL`s). Barmar found the link for that one.

Comment: @Chris: `char arr[4] = "hello";` has undefined behavior regardless of whether the array is accessed at all because it has too many non-null characters, and C 2018 6.7.9 2, which is in a Constraints section, says “No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.” (`char arr[4] = "hell";` would be defined because 6.7.9 14 says the final null character need not be included.) Also, it is null character, not `NULL`. `NULL` is an identifier for a null pointer constant. It is not a name for a character or a general name for a zero value.

Comment: @Chris: ASCII has a character called `NUL` (not `NULL`), but that is not a C thing.